# How to merge 2 CSV dataframes together for comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I have the first dataframe like this:

```
  New_cases
     Date_reported  
     February     10
     March       100
     April       200
     May         400
     June       1000
     July       1500
     August     1600
     September  1700
     October    1800
     November   1900
```

I have a 2nd dataframe like this:

```
    Variables   Hotel Room Revenue (Thousand Dollars)   Standard Average Hotel Occupancy Rate * (Per Cent)
        2020 Feb    193,213.60  49.70
        2020 Mar    120,062.60  39.90
        2020 Apr    57,363.60   38.20
        2020 May    41,068.30   57.50
        2020 Jun    35,903.50   53.30
        2020 Jul    34,009      70.00
        2020 Aug    58,377.40   63.10
        2020 Sep    57,563.10   61.50
        2020 Oct    66,711.90   57.60
        2020 Nov    66,280.90   53.80
```

I want to merge 2 tables together to produce a relationship graph with the month as the key. How to go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

First you will need something you can join on. You've got the full month on one side and the three-letter month on the other. I would start by making a new column on the first data set that had a three-letter month.

Then you can do something like:

```
new_df = df_left.merge(df_right, on="month")
```

You just need something that will match in both dataframes. For more information, check out: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
merged_left = pd.merge(left=survey_sub, right=species_sub, how='left', left_on='species_id', right_on='species_id')
merged_left
```

Also, the pandas merge function supports two other join types:

```
Right (outer) join: Invoked by passing how='right' as an argument. Similar to a left join, except all rows from the right DataFrame are kept, while rows from the left DataFrame without matching join key(s) values are discarded.

Full (outer) join: Invoked by passing how='outer' as an argument. This join type returns the all pairwise combinations of rows from both DataFrames; i.e., the result DataFrame will NaN where data is missing in one of the dataframes. This join type is very rarely used.
```

See the links below for more info.

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/joining-dataframes-pandas

https://datacarpentry.org/python-ecology-lesson/05-merging-data/index.html